# Combining two CharSequence variables

Tags: java, android, charsequence

Can I combine two `CharSequence` variables like this?

```
if (status == 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < get.length(); i++) {
        if (get.charAt(i) == ')') {
        } else {
            temp = temp.toString() + get.charAt(i);     
            // temp and get are charSequence VARIABLES
        }
    }
}
```

Syntax is looking OK as no errors from compiler, but the app is crashing.

Also I don't want to get in `List` and `ArrayList` items at this beginner stage. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Also if you say that I shouldn't use `.toString()` method then I understand but what should I do then to make it correct?

Comment: Because of `toString()` you are doing String concatenation. What error is your app crashing with?

Comment: working on making calculator thats why exluding closing paranthesis in if statemnet....

Comment: it just crashes.... Force close

Comment: Use logcat to find out why.

Comment: i think thread exiting with uncaught exception... am i accessing out of bound here?

Comment: Also, this is a very inefficient way to do it; use `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

are you sure `get` is not null ?

i tried your code and it's working.

debug and provide values for which your app is crashing.

and you can achieve the same result with :

```
temp = temp.toString() + get.toString().replaceAll("\\)", "");
```

Comment: yp i m sure get is not null... but your line code looks intersting... let me try.

Comment: what about `temp ` variable, can it be `null` ?

Comment: umm. actually i want to solve it in if statement when i encounter a closing braces.. so i dont want to just convert whole "get charSequence variable" in one line.... i need to got through all characters and respond as i receive characters....

Comment: @Muneeb you are calling `.toString()` method, and it will throw a `NullPointerException` causing your app to crash

Comment: oh alright.... can i initiate temp cahrSequence varaible like that

charSequence temp = "";

will tht be null now? if its still then how can i initiate it so tht it wont matter on the first iteration of loop?

cause what u r suggesting it loooks like this problem wil only arouse in first iteration of the loop....

Comment: @Muneeb yes, use `temp = "";`

Answer (score 1):

Well first you can think about refactoring code a little:

```
if (status == 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < get.length(); i++) {
        if (!(get.charAt(i) == ')')) {
            temp += get.charAt(i);
        }                
    }
}
```

The error you are encountering is in the different place of your code. This one cant throw an exception.

Also for parsing, you should think about regular expressions:

```
String tryThis = temp.replaceAll("\\)", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine, but what is the main objective that are you looking for?

Generally for such things we use `String` because it has various methods. Also, you can go with `StringBuffer` but the first thing should be what is the main objective.

Comment: main objective is to make a calculator like casio :). user will enter an algebric expression and i need to get its answer... so the expression is in character format... at this moment i m trying to solve the brackets first... thats why i need to break this expression to solve it...